# How to link table row content to source in Power View

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerview, powerbi, powerquery

I am currently able to use Power View to view, filter, and highlight my data. However I haven't figured out a way to link my table rows to the data source (i.e. tables in other tabs of the Excel spreadsheet).

so that if I double-click on a row, Excel will direct me to the appropriate table and show me the full content of that row (so that I can see data in the other columns that I wasn't showing in the Power View dashboard).

For example, I wouldn't put a "Description" column into the dashboard but I would want the user to be able to find and see the paragraph-long description for each item if he or she chooses to drill down.

See image [image]

I want to be able to click on any of those five line items and go to that table with that table filtered for only that item.

Does any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that's supported in Power View. 
HTH,
-Lukasz